# cygwin: line numbers in vi or vim have too much space in front, how is it removed?

Tags: vim, cygwin, vi

Using the a recent or latest cygwin x86_64 version, Setup.exe version 2.871 (64 bit), when I use the vi or vim editor, and do a:

```
:set number
```

command, the line numbers appear, but are indented quite a few spaces, taking away from useful editing/screen space.

I use a larger editing window that fits the width of my screen, however this smaller one shows the problem, and I want more space on my larger windows as I use my main monitors in portrait mode, not landscape.

[image]

Is this easily fixed? Note the file is less than 500 lines (i.e. it's not like 100,000 lines "semi-justifying" the need for all that space.)

Comment: Looks like it's due to that word `It's` in the margin, not necessarily the numbering.

Comment: Are you even in `nocompatible` mode?

Comment: No, that's not it -- the word "It's"  -- if I spread out the window and the word wrap goes away the problem is still there, I should have showed that more clearly, definitely misleading in hindsight.  ;-)

Comment: No, not in nocompatible mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vim, you can influence the width of the number column by the 'numberwidth' setting. You can't however have a smaller width, that the largest number would be wide (e.g. you can't set the width to 3 while you have more than 999 lines.)

Read the details at `:h 'numberwidth'`

Comment: Thanks, might you give an example and update that last sentence, didn't quite get you.  Thank you.

Comment: I have VIM version 7.4, which supports changing "gutter column width", as it's described in the online help.   So I do, :set numberwidth=3, and I see no change.  Is that what you'd expect?  NEVER MIND, THANKS, IT WORKED A SECOND TIME, NOT SURE WHY FIRST TIME DIDN"T

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean with gutter column. but if you have a sign column you can remove that if you remove all placed signs. `:sign unplace *` should do it. That however sounds more like you have a plugin that is placing signs, vim by itsself does not do that.